# Change exe file association for single user

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts, file-association

it is relatively easy to set the file association for `exe` files in windows (a nice way to lock yourself out, btw). This is typically done in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, which is valid for all users. But is there a way to change this association only for a single user?

I want to perform some action every time before some program is started by this user. The launcher should then call the program. However, `CreateProcess` does not work if elevation is required, while `ShellExecute` will run the launcher recursively... - so the idea was to execute the program from a different user which has not set the file association for the exe file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I don't know that there is a solution for what you're looking for, but it is a pretty spiffy "would be nice" feature.  +1 for that.  (and I don't even like windows)

Comment: @killermist: Yes, you can; just use `HKCU\Software\Classes`

Comment: @SLaks is correct about setting a file association for a single user, but it doesn't sound like this solves your problem. As you say, `ShellExecute` will just recursively call itself (unless you set the association to an executable file type that is not `.exe`). If you want a specific program to run through some launcher, you probably want [`Image File Execution Options`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/04/28/121871.aspx).

Comment: @CBHacking: I'm pretty sure ShellExecute will not recurse.  I've seen messed-up systems where `exefile` was changed, and it properly launched the wrong program (and was useless); it did not give any kind of stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

HKCR is an amalgamation of `HKLM\Software\Classes` and `HKCU\Software\Classes`.

You can simply create `HKCU\Software\Classes\.exe` and change the file association for the current user only.